# index.html home link broken. Goes to c:\

Tags: html

my new projects index.html home link is broken. When I click my home page it takes me to my C:/ Index of C instead of my home page. I've set my home page as "/"

Comment: Check in address bar, is it started with file:// (file) or http:// (web page)? If you load it as file, / will be the drive root. You must load it as web page so that / point to the home page root

Comment: and how do I load it or set it as a web page?

Comment: By using http server